# new line using '\n' in the string not working in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am unable to insert new line using \n or anything in string value in vue js, any suggestion to pass string value with  new line to the variable and it will show on html like -

String 1
String 2
String 3

Answer (score 0):

**Wrap the content in a pre element.**

A <pre element will preserve whitespace within it, eg:

```
<pre>New line here!
Yo it's a new line!</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `style="white-space: pre-wrap;"` in your element then it will work. more information about [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: "Hello Vue! It's a good day.\nBe happy!"
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" v-text="message" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></div>
```